# Create a date with a locale in moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to generate a EU date, which is typically in the format of `DD/MM/YYYY`.

```
// August 1st, 2018, EU format is DD/MM/YYYY
const myDate = moment('01/08/2018').locale('fr'); 
console.log(myDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Try pasting this code in [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com) console, and it doesn't work.

I expected `08/01/2018`, however I get `01/08/2018` back. It seems like it doesn't respect the locale date format.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct language file?

Comment: You can go to MomentJS and paste the above code and it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

On MomentJS site it is clearly specified that:

> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

You need to pass the format, as the string is not in ISO format.

If you need to leverage locale information, use the script which has support for locale information. Then, you can set the locale using `moment.locale` first, and then use `L` format specifier (for short date) to parse the date as per the locale's specifications.

See the demo below:

```js
moment.locale('fr');

const myDate = moment('01/08/2018', 'L'); 
console.log(myDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @kidcapital - Did it work for you? Please consider accepting the answer if so, otherwise let me know if you're facing problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using moment locales you will either need to import each language file you require into the page. They are normally located in /locale/fr.js.

If you require lots of language files to be loaded you can instead link to moment-with-locales.js which is served alongside moment.js in most CDNs or in the download from Moment's website.

By default Moment ships with 'en' as the language which is actually en-US